# How to specify username and password in ftp command?

Tags: ftp

I want to automate a call to ftp in a shell script. If I type

```
$ftp somehost.domain.com
```

I am prompted for a username and password. I want to give that username and password as part of the call to ftp. The [man page](http://ss64.com/bash/ftp.html) for ftp says I can issue a user command at the ftp prompt -- but I want to login to ftp all in one go. Is that possible? I don't see anything in the flags for ftp. I see that the -s option give me the option of specifying some ftp commands once I have the ftp prompt -- but I need to give the user name to get to the prompt...

Comment: `expect` (a tcl/tk extension of sorts) is a program that's ideal for this sort of things - ie. wait for some prompt; give a reponse... wait for an answer; give a new response...  `expect` wait for "ogin:" and send you username, then it wait for "assword:" and send your password.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a `.netrc` file in your home directory.

The content is:

```
# machine <hostname> login <username> password <password>
machine ftp.example.com login myuser password $ecret
```

If this is something you're doing programmatically, write the `.netrc` before connecting, delete it when you're done.

Comment: is this file specific to `ftp` or is it read by other programs also?

Comment: The `netrc(5)` man page says that it's "for `ftp(1)`" but I'm not sure that `ftp` is the only thing that will use it.

Comment: If you want to find your ".netrc" file just use this command: `locate '.netrc'`

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a c shell script using a [here doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) which would go something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
HOST='someftpserver.com'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'
FILES='*.txt'
#
ftp -nv $HOST>$FTPLOG <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd somedirectory
binary
mget $FILES
quit
END_SCRIPT
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider `wput` or `wget` as alternatives, depending on your needs.

I haven't used `wget` recently but I have used `wput` because I didn't want to create or modify files as suggested in some earlier answers.

For `wput`, the syntax is:

```
wput <filename> ftp://<username>:<password>@<address>
```